# Filtering on Column by a Value That Changes Depending on an MultiIndex Level

Tags: python, pandas, filter, multi-index

Complicated title but pretty simple problem.  I have a DataFrame with a MultiIndex:

[image]

I'd like rows of the frame above but the `'Filter Column'` must be greater than or equal to the values in the `filter_value` series below.

```
filter_value = Series([1, 3], ['red', 'blue'])
```

The correct solution for this toy problem would be the same dataframe but with only the `(red, 2)`, `(blue, 2)` and `(blue, 3)` rows left.

To set up for the above Frame:

```
arrays = [['red', 'red', 'blue', 'blue', 'blue'], [1, 2, 1, 2, 3]]
idx = MultiIndex.from_arrays(arrays, names=['Color', 'Count'])

values = Series(2, idx, name='Value')
ratios = Series(range(5), idx, name='Filter Column')
df = concat([values, ratios], axis='columns')
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Seem like you need `get_level_values` + `map`, then using the value comparison get the Boolean filter the df

```
df[df['Filter Column'].values>=df.index.get_level_values(0).map(filter_value)]
Out[108]: 
             Value  Filter Column
Color Count                      
red   2          2              1
blue  2          2              3
      3          2              4
```

Comment: @rhaskett yep, since you have multiple index and pandas is index sensitive, I have the habit using the values for safety since I usually do assign as well  :-)

Answer (score 2):

You can try this:

```
pd.concat(df.align(filter_value.rename('filter'), level=0, axis=0), axis=1)\
  .loc[lambda x: x['Filter Column']>=x['filter']]
```

Output:

```
             Value  Filter Column  filter
Color Count                              
red   2          2              1       1
blue  2          2              3       3
      3          2              4       3
```